# Temp Folder being deleted in users %appdata%

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, temporary-files

While generating reports our application stores data in a user's %appdata%/local/temp directory (using DevExpress report libraries - we have no control over this).

This works fine, except at 3pm, daily, at one of our clients (Running Windows Server 2016), when an incremented numbered folder in the user Temp directory (e.g. %appdata%/local/temp/96) is deleted, and requires either a new windows session to be started or SQL Server Mgmt studio to be opened to regain it.

We have gone through their scheduled tasks and have found nothing to explain it, their scheduled Disk Clean up runs weekly and not at 3pm, and there are no other 'CCleaner' style applications installed.

We have seen this at no other clients.

What may be causing this deletion and how can we stop it from happening?

Comment: Did you find which process was doing it in the end?

Comment: @Tomas, no, funnily enough, when we told out client we could monitor it, it strangely stopped ... I've never been one to blame a customer for problems on a project, but this is the closest I've got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can help you monitor the system to log what application is deleting the folder.

Comment: Great idea, foolishly didn't consider procmon,