# Windows 10 cleaning up my Temp dir too often

Tags: windows, windows-10, temporary-files

I started an [R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/) session 8 hours ago, and the temporary directory (in \AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWAzBY9) has already been deleted *while the R session is still running*. I got an error in R saying that the tempdir doesn't exist any more. How do I explain to my Windows 10 to not delete Temp so often?

This is the overview of my Startup processes from Task Manager, just to make sure no application is doing that. CCleaner is not doing it, I've installed it few days ago and this is a long term problem.

[image]

Comment: How do you know it is "Windows" doing it and not your R editor? If you actually care about the data you should not rely on a TEMP directory to store it for more than 5 seconds...

Comment: @Mokubai Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The temp directory gets deleted *while the R session is still running*. No exiting. So basically, someone deleted the R's temp dir under its ass. And then I got an error in R saying that the tempdir doesn't exist any more. Updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Okay, that's not right, though I doubt it is Windows itself. Microsoft is pretty happy for the TEMP directory to get pretty full and i don't see any hints that it runs automatically without you having set it up first (https://www.google.com/search?q=disk+cleanup+scheduled+task). Does your AVG have a "system optimiser" module? [AVG Tuneup](https://www.avg.com/en-gb/avg-pctuneup) perhaps? How long was this session running for?

Comment: I would shut off any cleaning/optimizing tools (AVG, CCleaner) and try again. It's very unlikely that Windows is doing this by itself.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1463748/temp-folder-being-deleted-in-users-appdata?rq=1

Comment: @Mokubai 22 hours, as mentioned in the question. Thanks for the tips! No AVG Tuneup.

Comment: Now even after just 8 hours!

Comment: First of all, Windows is not deleting your temp files.  I myself would go crazy knowing something was doing it.  Second.. just for this case, create a batch file.  set TEMP=<some_other_dir> THEN launch your "R" IDE.  Your IDE isn't very good if it doesn't lock files open that it needs to run.  Inexcusable bug.